# jQuery find next or previous table row by class across mutiple tables

Tags: jquery

How can I select the previous or next table row across multiple tables?

I am using keydown() with the arrow keys to select the table rows and highlighting each one in turn.

This is simple enough within one table using nextAll(), however how do I continue on to the next table below or above?

The table with the rows being selected is two levels deep:

```html
<table id="releaseTable">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <table id="table1">
        <tr>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <table>
              <tr>
                <td class="track">Row to select</td>
                <td class="track">Row to select</td>
                <td class="track">Row to select</td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <table id="table2">
        <tr>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <table>
              <tr>
                <td class="track">Row to select</td>
                <td class="track">Row to select</td>
                <td class="track">Row to select</td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Maybe [this plugin](http://www.arronwoods.com/blog/2011/04/jquery-find-next-element-in-dom-by-selector/) can help

Comment: Thank you miro.  I tested that plugin and it returns ALL of the next elements, not the actual next element.

Comment: Where is the JS code that you have tried?

Comment: Using the above plugin:  focusedRow = focusedRow.nextElementInDom('.track'); focusedRow.toggleClass('focused'); - With ´focusedRow' being the current row with focus, all elements receive the 'focused' class, not just the next

Comment: I cannot see doing this with jQuery without using a whole silly bunch of parent().  I think that just looping through .track, finding the one that has the 'focused' class and then add it to the next/previous one in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
var next = false;
$('.track').each(function() {
    if(next == true) {
        focusedRow = $(this);
        focusedRow.toggleClass('focused');
        next = 2;
    }                   
    if($(this).hasClass('focused') && next != 2) {
        next = true;
        focusedRow.toggleClass('focused');
    }
});
```

If you are wondering why I do not 'return' on the loop, it is because this code is within other code that must continue to execute.

Selecting the previous row is similar.